# Internal and external SD storage inaccessible as root

Tags: root-access, external-sd, mount, file-permissions, oppo-find-7

I'm having a bizarre issue where apps, adb, etc. can properly access my internal and external SD storage without issue **unless they are running as root**, in which case they are completely inaccessible.  This is on my Oppo Find 7 running ColorOS 1.2.7i (Android 4.3), and I've verified that I am not suffering from [this issue](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=57330783&postcount=42) with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.  I am not sure when this started occurring but I think it was after an OS update quite a while back.

When I run `mount` in an unprivileged adb shell, it has these entries that do not appear when I run it as the superuser:

```
/dev/block/vold/179:65 /storage/sdcard1 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1023,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:29 /storage/sdcard0 ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,discard,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:29 /mnt/secure/asec ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,discard,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /storage/sdcard0/.android_secure tmpfs ro,seclabel,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
```

**I can remount those partitions elsewhere while root and access them just fine within the same shell**, but the permissions are funky and no other root apps can access them:

```
$ su
# mkdir /storage/sd_test
# chmod 777 /storage/sd_test
# ls -al /storage | grep sd_test
# drwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-05-28 15:17 sd_test
```

... good so far ...

```
# mount -o rw,user,umask=0000 -t vfat /dev/block/vold/179:65 /storage/sd_test
# ls -al /storage | grep sd_test
d---rwxr-x system   media_rw          2015-05-28 15:00 sd_test
# chmod 777 /storage/sd_test
# ls -al /storage | grep sd_test
d---rwxr-x system   media_rw          2015-05-28 15:00 sd_test
```

... different permissions, but I can see and read/write the files inside ...

[image: screenshot from another app]

... Root Explorer shows it with the "original" permissions but the folder is empty ...

```
# mount | grep sd_test
/dev/block/vold/179:65 /storage/sd_test vfat rw,dirsync,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1023,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

... hmm.

My `/etc/vold.fstab` just has one line:

```
dev_mount sdcard /storage/sdcard1 auto /devices/msm_sdcc.2/mmc_host
```

And `/fstab.qcom`:

```
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system         /system      ext4    ro,barrier=1,discard                                wait
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata       /data        ext4    nosuid,nodev,barrier=1,noauto_da_alloc,discard      wait,check,encryptable=footer
/devices/msm_sdcc.2/mmc_host                          /storage/sdcard1   vfat    nosuid,nodev         wait,voldmanaged=sdcard:auto
/devices/msm_sdcc.1/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0         /storage/sdcard0   ext4    nosuid,nodev,barrier=1,noauto_da_alloc,discard        wait,voldmanaged=sdcard:29
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: First  Android 4.2.2 and earlier, the device-specific vold.fstab configuration file defines mappings from sysfs devices to filesystem mount points, and each line follows this format dev_mount <label> <mount_point> <partition> <sysfs_path> [flags] Yourdevice dev_mount sdcard /storage/sdcard1 auto /devices/msm_sdcc.2/mmc_host. Cont. Next comment.

Comment: Android releases 4.3 and later, the various fstab files used by init, vold and recovery were unified in the /fstab.<device> file. For external storage volumes that are managed by vold, the entries should have the following format. <src> <mnt_point> <type> <mnt_flags> <fs_mgr_flags
Do you understand the format your running is for 4.2.2 and below as stated in post color OS 4.3 which is wrong format ([reference](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config.html))

Comment: @BoLawson I tried copying `/fstab.qcom` over top of `/etc/vold.fstab` and rebooting, but there is no change in behavior.

Comment: I'm looking I would say go to the source code for your  OS and get the device-specific storage_list.xml somewhere around frameworks /base/something: xml to get the storage_list.xml which has the mount points. But I think color os is closed sourced I just have not found the legit one. I am unsure but I think Sdk platform might have them  through I am researching. This is the [storage_list.xml] (https://android.googlesource.com/device/moto/wingray/+/master/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/xml/storage_list.xml) **not your device** file you are looking for and at the bottom is the mount points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that SuperSU automatically checked off its "Mount namespace separation" setting without telling me!  I had no idea it even had such a feature, much less that it was broken.

Comment: Good that you figured it out already. Could you tell us how did you end up at this conclusion? That may help somebody in troubleshooting a similar case.

Comment: @Firelord Luck, really.  I was going through SuperSU's settings and saw it, and immediately realized it was probably causing the issue.