# What does "mount namespace separation" in the app SuperSU do?

Tags: root-access, supersu

The title pretty much says it all. What does  "mount namespace separation" in the app SuperSU do and how does it affect other apps?

Answer (score 6):

From the man page for `mount`:

> A mount namespace is the set of filesystem mounts that are visible to a process.

It makes it so that the superuser has separate mount points visible to it from the rest of the system/apps.  I believe the intention is to prevent any issues when remounting partitions, such as remounting `/system` as read-write.  With this option enabled it should remain read-only to unprivileged apps.

It can, however, just break things more.  It made my SD card unusable in root apps: [Internal and external SD storage inaccessible as root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110658/1465)

Comment: +1. Using *Systemless root*, in my case, unchecking it works fine and resolved TiBu issues too