# How to make bind-mounted (mount -o bind) folders visible for non-root users?

Tags: file-system, mount

I want to mount-bind an app data folder in `/data/data/...` to a user subfolder in order to automatically synchronize the contents for backup purposes. As root I use the following command:

```
mount -o bind /data/data/org.blabla.app/database/ /storage/emulated/0/blabla_database
```

The command seems to work and I can access the files in the mounted folder as long as I am root. However, as soon as I exit root, the files become invisible and the bind-mounted folder is empty.

How can I make the files visible for non-root users so that my sync app can access the files for backup?

Comment: Just a guess: Are you using SuperSU? If so, please check whether switching off "mount namespaces" helps. For details, see [What does “mount namespace separation” in the app SuperSU do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/142727/16575)

Comment: Thank you Izzy, you are right! Un-checking "mount namespace separation" in the SuperSU preferences makes a difference. But here comes the weird part: When I change back from root to normal user in the remote SSH, which I am using, I can effectively see the bind-mounted files now. But the files remain still invisible in the file manager and even if I open a new Termux shell and cd into the folder. Isn't that weird?? If I change to root (su -) in Termux I can see the files again %-( Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately no more ideas, sorry. Hopefully someone else can pick up from here.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have different file ownership and permissions for every app in `/sdcard`, since Android 6 every app is run in an **isolated mount namespace**. `/storage/emulated` is bind mounted for every app with **private / slave mount propagation** to a different VIEW:

```
/mnt/runtime/default/emulated
/mnt/runtime/read/emulated
/mnt/runtime/write/emulated
```

It depends on if the app has `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission granted or not. For details see [What is the “u#_everybody” UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526)

Mounting directly to `/storage/emulated` won't appear in apps' mount namespaces unless you enter every app's mount namespace explicitly. The same is true if you mount from some app's isolated mount namespace as mentioned by @[Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) in comment. See [Partition gets unmounted automatically in Android Oreo](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200449/218526).

So you need to mount from root mount namespace to one of the above VIEWs, so that mount is propagated to all apps' mount namespaces.

For more details see [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526)