# How do I make mounts in /data/local/ visible to other apps?

Tags: root-access, mount

I've seen [Why (bind) mounts in /storage/emulated/0 are not visible in apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194651/why-bind-mounts-in-storage-emulated-0-are-not-visible-in-apps) but I don't understand how to apply the method to /data/local/

Comment: kindly explain background for */data/local* why not use */mnt/media_rw* + */storage* like usual, and what android version we are talking about

Comment: And what rooting solution are you using? Have you turned off the [isolated mount namespaces](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200449/218526)?

Comment: I have a chroot in /data/local/ and am mounting an image in the chroot itself using Termux with magisk su

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks, that was the solution, how do I mark the url as the answer?

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Just want to let you know that comments and links cannot be marked as an answer. Since Irfan's link helped you, it's assumed that this issue is similar/same to that question since the answer explains why and how to solve it and applies to both situation.