# sd card is empty when using su

Tags: sd-card, supersu

I have strange issue.

I've just installed **Supersu**.

With regular user (not su ) the sdcard shows all contents as usual,

But on doing  **su** , I see (with "ls") that /**sdcard** is empty (though it is not) !, on going back to regular user, I see files again....

Any idea what's wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: Try toggling *mount space separation* in Su app settings

Comment: magnificent, thank you so much. I will write is as a solution

Comment: yes please, the credit is yours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely due to *mount namespace separation* being unchecked in SuperSU app settings

For an explanation of what it does and how it could possibly affect storage not being read see Mathew's answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/142729/131553), also the link referred to therein

Aside, sometimes TiBu also asks you to do the same if SD is not recognised

Comment: This is a very non-obvious UX bug, thanks for sharing the fix!

Comment: @develCuy:Anytime. Glad it helped