# How to fix sdcard empty under root with Kingoroot?

Tags: rooting, root-access, sd-card, mount, internal-sd

My sdcard is empty when I use `su`. I have gained root using Kingoroot.
[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/165460/302225) shows the SuperSU solution (mount namespace separation).

How to mount an sdcard to `su`? What additional information should I provide to get help?

It's a MTK device with Android 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I never used Kingoroot, so can't be sure if it provides and option for master mount (`su mm`) or not. You can switch to Magisk or SuperSU once the device is rooted. If you can't or don't want to, you can use:

```
su -c 'nsenter -t 1 -m /system/bin/sh'
```

from commandline instead of simple `su`. This will make you switch to root mount namespace. For details see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200449/218526).
`nsenter` is usually available as busybox applet.

Since mount namesapce was [implemented](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526) in Android 6, this might not be the problem with your KK device.

**PS:**
If Kingoroot works for you, it indicates that your device has some serious [security flaw(s)](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205707/218526). Do consider an upgrade.

Comment: Empty output, as well as /storage/sdcard0

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uZwv5GYG

Comment: The link you provided contains "DISABLE INTERNAL MEMORY (/data/media/0) AND USE EXTERNAL SD CARD AS INTERNAL STORAGE" But /data/media/ contains only an `obb` folder

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RGaR7grk  `mount /dev/block/vold/179:8 /my_sdcard` still gives `Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory`

Comment: I have rebooted the device and `mount -o rw,remount /; mkdir /my_sdcard; mount -t vfat /dev/block/vold/179:8 /my_sdcard` kinda works `ls /my_sdcard` shows the list of files on the sdcard. `/my_sdcard` is still empty in root explorer

Comment: I did  `mount -o uid=0,gid=0 -t vfat /dev/block/vold/179:8 /my_sdcard`, `mount` still shows uid=1023,gid=1023